Why does VS Codes's Python REPL window output letters with wrong encoding?
My file setting in VS Code is set to UTF-8 (default) rendering. If I run my line via Shift+Enter, the python Native REPL opens but i get the wrong encoding as i show below. However, If i run using the interactive window (jupyter) or via the terminal I get the correct rendering.
example code:
print('Accented letters: á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ')

I get this wrong output as follows:
Accented letters: Ã¡, Ã©, Ã­, Ã³, Ãº, Ã¼, Ã±


I can't reproduce this; both .ipynb files and the # %% cell notation are working fine for me. Can you provide more debugging steps?

Not sure how i can oprovide more details. i'm running the code snippets using shift enter, which opens the vscode interactive python repl. String outputs there are scrambled, obviously encoding problem.

Ok so aparently i'm running lines in python REPL via shift+enter. I If you right click at a line, you can select run python-> run line in PYthon REPL (which looks exatcly like the interactive window if you right click then select run in interactive window). If i run in interactive window, the output is encoded correctly. But what is the difference between the interactive window and the python REPL? they both look and behave the same apart from the encoding problem. and why do i get an enconding problem running via Python REPL?

Consider writing an [edit] to address those issues. Don't write a big "EDIT:" section, but do update your questions with those details since they'll be relevant to any good answer.

I'm assuming you are a Windows user? It isn't a question of whether the Python REPL and the IPython interactive window are doing anything different. The question is what encoding the console/terminal that REPL is running in. You are using utf-8 in Python but your IO boundary in the terminal is not UTF-8.

I see, i thought the python REPL would be using the same encoding as the terminal and I was xonfused because the terminal output is corrert. How can I set the REPL encoding to utf-8?


set the REPL encoding to utf-8?

The code below works for me:
print(('Accented letters: á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8'))

